# python locate items in lists of list and 'float' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, list, enumerate

I'm trying to locate items in lists of list and use the items to do calculation. But `TypeError: 'float' object is not subscriptable` occurred.

Here's the question/lists:

```
history_lists=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1],[5,8,0,1]]
```

I want to locate the last two item in each list in `history_lists`, and calculate the average.

Here's my codes:

```
def get_question(self):

    combined_lists_history.append(var1)
    combined_lists_history.append(var2)

    history_lists = [[] for _for _ in range(max(combined_lists_history[1::2]))]

    for i in range(1, len(combined_lists_history),2):
           history_lists[combined_lists_history[i]-1].append(combined_lists_history[i-1])

 # this codes are for recreating a list of lists
 # combined_lists_history = [1,**1**,3,**1**,5,**3**,4,**1**,2,**2**,3,**2**,1,**2**,8,**3**,0,**3**,1,**3**,2,**1**,]
 # history_lists=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1],[5,8,0,1]]

def get_avg(self):

    for i, lst in enumerate(history_lists):
           (history_lists[i][-1] + history_lists[i][-2])/2.0 
          # for each list in history_lists, retrieve last two item
```

Comment: I'm unsure about the error but in any case I don't think your program will do what you expect. You have a for loop with a return statement. This means that the program will only ever go ONCE in the loop and return. your entire code block is equivalent to `return (history_lists[0][-1] + history_lists[0][-2])/2.0` . Maybe you want to print instead of return? Or stored in somewhere and print the whole thing at the end of the loop?

Comment: Why `return`? If you're looking to make a generator then use `yield`. Also, don't name a variable `list`. `list(map(lambda x: sum(x[-2:])/2.0, history_lists))` should get you far.

Comment: the error is not located in the code you provided. Full stacktrace and code please?

Comment: I just ran this and didn't have any errors. Also change `return` to `print` and don't use variables native to Python as names for your other variables.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this succinctly with a list comprehension:

```
history_lists=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1],[5,8,0,1]]
averages=[(history_list[-1] + history_list[-2]) / 2.0 for history_list in history_lists]
```

Your error was likely because whatever is calling your function is expecting a `list` to be returned but since you're using `return` in your loop it's instead receiving a single float. This will be fixed by simply returning the `averages` list as generated above.

**Edit: Added missing parentheses**

Comment: Ah yes, missed the parentheses, thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

Using your style, instead of more Pythonic approaches:

```
history_lists=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1],[5,8,0,1]]
averages = []

# Don't use "list" as a variable name since that's a keyword
for lst in history_lists:
    avg = (lst[-1] + lst[-2]) / 2.0
    averages.append(avg)

print averages
```

Alternatively, if you want all of them averaged:

```
history_lists=[[1,2,3,4],[2,3,1],[5,8,0,1]]
total_count = 0
total_sum = 0

for lst in history_lists:
    total_count += 2.0
    total_sum += lst[-1] + lst[-2]

total_average = total_sum / total_count

print total_average
```

Answer (score -2):

i think you want to do something more along these lines...

```
average = 0
for list in history_lists:
    final += (list[-1] + list[-2])/2
print average
```

Comment: note: the answer must be in python language, not p++ (I just made that up). That's too bad because I'm willing to encourage first-time posters...

Comment: answer syntax corrected. I've been writing a lot of c# lately so it kind of got mixed in there, but should be right now.